Optimism L1 fee calculation
I've submitted a transaction on BASE, which is one of the OP stack chains.
This is the transaction I sent:
curl --location 'https://sepolia.base.org' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "method": "eth_getTransactionReceipt",
    "params": [
        "0xc11e3ff41cefed69f6a74d6e236ce66c87ededa97eea364cf12ac53141f86274"
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}'

I see there are 3 fields in the response:

l1Fee: 31248
l1GasPrice: 17701
l1GasUsed: 1600

These values are consistent with the explorer: https://sepolia.basescan.org/tx/0xc11e3ff41cefed69f6a74d6e236ce66c87ededa97eea364cf12ac53141f86274
According to Quicknode document, the l1fee equals to l1GasPrice * l1GasUsed
ref: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/optimism/eth_getTransactionReceipt
However it is not , and the result 28321600  is apparently much bigger than actual fee.
Am I missing something in the formula?
Thanks

Great question. Upvoted it. I'm also waiting for the correct answer to the similar question that I'd posted a couple of months ago. Please upvote mine as well, so that it can get more attention.

The QuickNode formuala given above is roughly correct but misses a few details.

If we look at the GasPriceOracle.sol contract's getL1Fee() method we can follow _getL1FeeEcotone() since Ecotone is the current hardfork Base is running on.
_getl1FeeEcotone() calculates the L1Fee in 4 steps.

It calculates the l1GasUsedbased on the transaction data
It calculates a scaledBaseFee based on the baseFeeScalar which is a constant set by the chain.
It calculates a scaledBlobBaseFee by using the baseFeeScalar which is a constant set by the chain.
The final fee is calculated using the formula l1GasUsed * (scaledBaseFee + scaledBlobBaseFee)



These extra steps should end up making the difference between the answer you are calculating and what the L1Fee is. Also, please note this is the formula for the Ecotone hardfork and will change when Base implements the Fjord hardfork.
To learn more here are some references:

Ecotone L1GasFee docs
Fjord L1GasFee docs


Hey Zak, thanks for answering. I’ve also asked a similar question, related to generic way of calculating L2 transaction fee.

As far as I can understand, the L1 factors that we see on any L2 transaction, their values vary from chain to chain (depending on the corresponding rollup project and its stack like OP Stack and OVM, Arbitrum, StarkNet, zkSync Era, Linea, Scroll). But, is there a way to fetch those values so as to estimate the transaction cost, using some library like ethers.js or web3.js, instead of manually checking the network docs?

Great question, instead of keeping this in the comments, do you mind making this an actual StackExchange question and I can answer it there? That way it is easily searchable for others.

Actually, I’d already posted it as a question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162178/how-transaction-fee-is-calculated-in-case-of-l2.
